# I wonder if my code can be more optimized

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I'm student and taking Microprocessor class.

Because of COVID-19, I had gotten a simple mid-term assignment writing inline assembly code of QuickSort.

Today, I got a score of this assignment and the score was almost the lowest because of **"operation speed".** (scored by rank, that mean my code works much slower than anyone else in class)

I tried to optimize my code before submission. So I have no idea why does my code work slowly.

TA said it is **common for 85 ms to come out**, but my code has an execution speed of **400ms**.

I guess my code load a lot of unnecessary memory.

So my questions are:

1. Do I load unnecessary memory? (ie. Is my code use ldr, str instruction in unnecessary way?)
2. Does the number of memory loads affect the actual operation time?

Adding comment on "optimization", We only learned that the access speed of memory is slower then the register in the class, So I only tried to minimize the memory load and reduce unnecessary construction.

That mean someone can use "awesome tricks" to solve this problem but it is not general in my class.

Development environment:

- GNU C Compiller(GCC) in Arm cortex M0 processor and nano Editor

Here is my code:

```
void QuickSort(int* arr, int size, int pivot, int end) {    
int Lsize, Lstart, Lend, Rsize, Rstart, Rend;

//Note that all variables are mean index of Array, excep for temp
//so in inline assembly, We have to change them into byte
asm
(
        /*check Condition*/
        "MOV r10, #2\n\t"
        "CMP r1, r10\n\t"
        "BLT FINISH\n\t"

        /*Initialize*/
        "MOV r10, #4\n\t"           //r10 is temp value
        //"LDR r1, %[size]\n\t"     //r1 is size of arr    
        //"LDR r2, %[pivot]\n\t"    //r2 is pivot's address(start)
        "MUL r2, r2, r10\n\t"       
        //"LDR r3, %[end]\n\t"      //r3 is end's address
        "MUL r3, r3, r10\n\t"       
        "MOV r4, r2\n\t"            //r4 is low's address
        "ADD r4, r4, #4\n\t"        //low = pivot +1  
        "MOV r5, r3\n\t"            //r5 is high's address 

        /*Initialize for loop*/
        "LDR r6, [r0, r4]\n\t"      //let r6 as value of low
        "LDR r7, [r0, r2]\n\t"      //let r7 as value of pivot
        "LDR r8, [r0, r5]\n\t"      //let r8 as value of high

        /*Start Loop*/
        "B L6\n\t"                  //Check Condition First
        "LOOP2:\n\t"                //while(low <= high)

            "B L7\n\t"                  //check condition First
            "LOOP3:\n\t"                //while(arr[low]<=arr[pivot])
            "ADDS r4, r4, #4\n\t"       //low++
            "LDR r6, [r0,r4]\n\t"           //and update low's value
            "L7: CMP r6, r7\n\t"
            "BLE LOOP3\n\t"

            "B L8\n\t"                  //check condition First
            "LOOP4:\n\t"                //while(arr[high]>=arr[pivot])
            "SUBS r5, r5, #4\n\t"       //high--
            "LDR r8, [r0,r5]\n\t"       //and update high's value
            "L8: CMP r8, r7\n\t"        
            "BGE LOOP4\n\t"

            "CMP r5, r2\n\t"            //if(high<pivot)
            "BGE L9\n\t"
            "MOVS r5, r2\n\t"           //high = pivot
            "L9:\n\t"

            "CMP r4, r5\n\t"            //if(low >= high)
            "BGE END\n\t"               //break LOOP2 

            "LDR r9, [r0, r4]\n\t"      //store r9 value of low
            "LDR r10, [r0, r5]\n\t"     //store r10 value of high
            "STR r9, [r0, r5]\n\t"      
            "STR r10, [r0, r4]\n\t"

            "MOV r6, r10\n\t"
            "MOV r8, r9\n\t"

        "L6: CMP r4, r5\n\t"        //Compare whether low <= high
        "BLE LOOP2\n\t"             //If so, back to loop2
        "END: \n\t"                 //This is end of loop2   

        /*swap pivot and high*/
        "LDR r9, [r0, r5]\n\t"      //store r9 vlaue of high
        "LDR r10, [r0, r2]\n\t"     //store r10 value of pivot
        "STR r9, [r0, r2]\n\t"
        "STR r10, [r0,r5]\n\t"

        /*Set variables again*/
        //Note that we have to divide them in 4
        //Use r9 as quotient and r10 as zero
        "MOV r9, #0\n\t"
        "MOV r10, #0\n\t"
        "B D1\n\t"
        "sLoop1:\n\t"
        "ADD r9, r9, #1\n\t"
        "SUB r2, r2, #4\n\t"
        "D1: CMP r2, r10\n\t"
        "BGT sLoop1\n\t"
        "MOV r2, r9\n\t"      //pivot

        "MOV r9, #0\n\t"
        "B D2\n\t"
        "sLoop2:\n\t"
        "ADD r9, r9, #1\n\t"
        "SUB r3, r3, #4\n\t"
        "D2: CMP r3, r10\n\t"
        "BGT sLoop2\n\t"
        "MOV r3, r9\n\t"       //end

        "MOV r9, #0\n\t"
        "B D4\n\t"
        "sLoop4:\n\t"
        "ADD r9, r9, #1\n\t"
        "SUB r5, r5, #4\n\t"
        "D4: CMP r5, r10\n\t"
        "BGT sLoop4\n\t"
        "MOV r5, r9\n\t"   //high

        /*Let r10 a temp of argument*/
        "SUB r10, r5, r2\n\t"   //Lsize = high-pivot
        "STR r10, %[Lsize]\n\t"
        "STR r2, %[Lstart]\n\t" //Lstart = pivot
        "SUB r10, r5, #1\n\t"   //Lend=high-1
        "STR r10, %[Lend]\n\t"

        "SUB r10, r3, r5\n\t"   //Rsize = end-high
        "STR r10, %[Rsize]\n\t"
        "ADD r10, r5, #1\n\t"   //Rstart=high+1
        "STR r10, %[Rstart]\n\t"
        "STR r3, %[Rend]\n\t"   //Rend = end


    ://There is no output operands
    :[arr] "r"(arr), [size] "m"(size) ,[pivot] "m"(pivot),[end] "m"(end), [Lsize] "m"(Lsize), [Lstart] "m"(Lstart), [Lend] "m"(Lend), [Rsize] "m"(Rsize), [Rstart] "m"(Rstart), [Rend] "m"(Rend)

    :"r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8", "r9", "r10"
);
```

Comment: Why are you using `MUL` instead of bit shifts to compute the start and end indices?  This is likely not your problem, but it is something you could improve.

Comment: @fuz Actually I didn't know that '''mul'''  instruction takes longer time than bit shift thanks for your suggestion. Also after discussing with my friends, We found that students who use recursive call takes longer time than students who use loop(non-recursive way). Anyway I could learn many things through this assignment. Thank you again :)

Comment: Give me some time to try and find out why your code is slower than that of your classmates.  It is likely an algorithmic problem.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to post equivalent source-code in a higher level language (e.g. C).  I wonder whether you focussed on micro optimisations rather than implementing the optimal algorithm?

Comment: @fuz Oh, I just have seen your comment. Thank you. The code above is just a function in my code(Quicksort function and I call this function recursively in C). If you need my full code, tell me

Comment: @marko I already have C-version of this code. My assignment was changing that C code to inline assembly. So I  guess there will be no algorithmic problem.(Just my assumption). To answer your question, It is likely to say that I'm focusing on 'micro optimization'. I'm sorry that I made you confused..

Comment: *So I guess there will be no algorithmic problem* ... unless you made a mistake, e.g. possibly in pivot selection or in doing extra work or something.  But all of your slowdown might be explained by stuff like using a repeated subtraction loop to divide by a power of 2, instead of `lsr` for a 2-bit right shift!!  Computers use binary numbers; powers of 2 are very fast to multiply and divide using shifts.

Comment: `mul` takes two cycles while ALU instructions such as shift operations take one. Even worse, `mul` comes with a latency of three cycles. You should avoid `mul` wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I could get a precious lesson from my low score lol. I'll consider these things next time when I code assembly.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: [Processor instruction timings in Cortex-M3 Technical Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0337/e/instruction-timing/processor-instruction-timings)
says that `MUL is one cycle`.  I wasn't able to find a similar table
for Cortex-M0.